# How can Saved Instance State read/write to disk in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, savestate

According to Android developer documentation as of March 1, 2023, Saved Instance State is slow to read/write.
This is because it requires a serialization/deserialization process and requires ***disk access***.

My understanding is that Saved Instance State uses a Bundle object to store data, and the data will be restore using a Bundle object at `onCreate` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.

My question is, since the Bundle object will be stored in memory, **how can it access the disk to read/write the stored data?**

Due to these questions, I'm also confusing how SavedInstanceState can safely recover from process destruction, since at the time the process is destroyed by the System, the memory will also be destroyed.

Thanks.

I've attached a relevant developer documentation link and a diagram below.

[Android Developers - Save UI States](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#options)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the data needs to be stored to disk at some point.  The OS may actually terminate your process and restart it later, passing in a Bundle that matches the one your returned from saveInstanceState.  To make this happen, it needs to serialize it to disk, so it's saved between process instances.  Whether or not the OS actually will write it to disk is an implementation detail of the OS-  it may not in all cases.  But it can.

Of course since it's Bundle backed I wouldn't worry about the speed of reading the Bundle.  I'd worry more about the size limitation (which is 1-2MB) or a Bundle, and which you'll crash if you exceed.

Comment: A `Bundle` cannot be serialized to disk, because it can contain things that are not serializable, such as `IBinder` handles. Android 5.x introduced a separate pair of `onSaveInstanceState()` / `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods that take both a `Bundle` and a `PersistableBundle`. The latter *is* persisted, for things like reboots. The ordinary `Bundle` is simply held in system RAM.

Comment: Apparently the last time I looked at the doc was a bit dated-  what I wrote was true at one version, but the Binder stuff was added to Bundles in API 18.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, since the Bundle object will be stored in memory, how can it access the disk to read/write the stored data?

IMHO, this is a documentation bug. For the purposes of that table, I would have gone with "quick, but requires inter-process communication (IPC)". A classic `Bundle` is not persistable and is not persisted.

Android 5.x introduced a version of `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` that take both a `Bundle` and a `PersistableBundle`. The latter is indeed persisted. However, the first row of your table indicates to me that they are not considering that scenario.

Ideally, this table would have five columns, two of which are "Saved Instance State", covering the `Bundle` and the `PersistableBundle` scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I also thought it was strange to access the disk to read/write data.

So, can I understand that in Configuration Changed situations like screen rotation, we store data internally via Bundle, and in situations like System Memory Kill, we store data internally via PersistableBundle?

Comment: @JaesungLee: I do not know what you mean by "System Memory Kill". The `PersistableBundle` option was there to allow the task list to be restored after a reboot of the device.